# Print runtime of an optimizer

Tags: programming, quantum-computing-for-finance

I want to find the runtime of my program, i.e. the time it is in the quantum computer without queue time. However, I am using an optimizer so the code is a little different.

```
from qiskit.utils import algorithm_globals




algorithm_globals.random_seed = 1234
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_belem')

#backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')

cobyla = COBYLA()
cobyla.set_options(maxiter=1)
ry = TwoLocal(num_assets, 'ry', 'cz', reps=3, entanglement='full')
quantum_instance = QuantumInstance(backend=backend, seed_simulator=seed, seed_transpiler=seed)
vqe_mes = VQE(ry, optimizer=cobyla, quantum_instance=quantum_instance)
vqe = MinimumEigenOptimizer(vqe_mes)
result = vqe.solve(qp)



print(result)
#print_result(result)
```

How do I figure out the runtime? Printing result only shows

```
optimal function value: -0.01488461311339271
optimal value: [1. 0. 0. 1.]
status: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a `start` and `end_operation` point with the method `now()`. At the end of the operation it will display the time it needed:

```
from qiskit.utils import algorithm_globals
from time import time as now



algorithm_globals.random_seed = 1234
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_belem')

#backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')

cobyla = COBYLA()
cobyla.set_options(maxiter=1)
ry = TwoLocal(num_assets, 'ry', 'cz', reps=3, entanglement='full')
quantum_instance = QuantumInstance(backend=backend, seed_simulator=seed, seed_transpiler=seed)
start_operation = now()
vqe_mes = VQE(ry, optimizer=cobyla, quantum_instance=quantum_instance)
vqe = MinimumEigenOptimizer(vqe_mes)
end_operation = now()
result = vqe.solve(qp)

    
    process_time = (
end_operation - start_operation
)
print(f"Operation took {process_time:.2f} seconds in machine")



print(result)
#print_result(result)
```

---

Another possibility to meassure the program is to use the command `rep_time`:

> `rep_time` (int) – Time per program execution in seconds. Must be from
> the list provided by the backend
> (`backend.configuration().rep_times`). Defaults to the first entry.

In your specific case you need to add it in your code like this:

```
...
quantum_instance = QuantumInstance(backend=backend, rep_time=rep_time, seed_simulator=seed, seed_transpiler=seed)
...
```

Comment: I think the difference is that I'm using an optimizer as opposed to the typical job architecture

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-22-96ed0737ee6d>", line 17, in <module>
    vqe.status()
AttributeError: 'MinimumEigenOptimizer' object has no attribute 'status'

Use %tb to get the full traceback.

Comment: This is the error with the updated answer, and yes I am using qiskit

Comment: This gives me Generated circuits in 61.79 seconds
optimal function value: -0.01488461311339271
optimal value: [1. 0. 0. 1.]
status: SUCCESS

Comment: This is good, but I want to know how long it is in the quantum computer itself, not including the queue time. Through the status timeline I can see it was only in the quantum computer for 3.7 seconds. I want to run hundreds of tests and can't manually check the sidebar everytime

Comment: I don't think it is miliseconds, the queue time took about 55 seconds, so I think it was measuring the queue time as well.

Comment: This returns Generated circuits in 77.22 seconds
Done in 77224 ms.
optimal function value: -0.01488461311339271
optimal value: [1. 0. 0. 1.]
status: SUCCESS

Comment: However, this includes the time that the kernel is waiting for space in the quantum computer, and isn't what I want

Comment: I would like to print just the time that it is in the quantum computer, which for this piece of code is around 3.7 seconds or so

Comment: Yes hopefully! However, this is just returning the time the whole program takes which is going to change everytime because some of it is sent to the IBM quantum computer and thus has to wait in a queue for about 30-45 seconds, I don't want that time to be included.

Comment: This time it returned the operation taking 87 seconds, and the queue time was about 76 seconds which I can see through the IBM API but I can't figure out how to print it in my program

Comment: The problem is we aren't measuring the correct thing, this measures how long the process took locally, but the result = vqe.solve(qp) line sends code to the IBM servers, and I want to know how long it spends in the IBM servers.

Comment: I updated the answer. Founding another command called rep_time. Now you have 2 opportunities to measure your operation. Please let me know if the 2nd works as well. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that the second is the way to go, but I'm having trouble implementing it. Thank you for your help thusfar! I can't change the quantuminstance line in the way you have described as it returns an error

Comment: You are welcome! Feel free to tick the answer as correct. I made a lot of research and these 2 options are everything you can use for that measurement. You said you have problems implementing rep_time. I found this source code that can help you: https://qiskit.org/documentation/_modules/qiskit/compiler/assembler.html